# jQuery trigger(clickEvent) behaves differently to clicking the item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML5 canvas element, which the user can interact with, it has an onclick handler that just catches the event and stops it, as follows:

```
this.canvas.onclick = function(e){
    $("#mycanvas")[0].focus();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.bubbles = false;
};
```

I have an onclick handler on the document, as follows:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
  //do something I only want done when the canvas is NOT clicked
}
```

When I click on the canvas, as expected the `document.onclick` handler is not fired. However, I also need to be able to trigger the click programatically, for this I am using jQuery:

```
$("#mycanvas").trigger($.Event(savedClickEvent));
```

when this code runs, the `document.onclick` handler is triggered. From looking at the `jQuery.trigger` code, it seems to be wanting not only `stopPropagation()`, but also `preventDefault()`.

Why is there a discrepancy between the requirement of `preventDefault()` on click, and on trigger? Is this a bug in jQuery that I need to workaround, or should I not be calling `stopPropagation()` without `preventDefault()` - my understanding of these two functions is that they do fairly different things.

Bonus question: Why does `$("#mycanvas")[0].click` return `function(){[native code]}`? I suspect this is what is causing the problem.

Edit:
It seems jQuery doesn't support inline event handlers. Using addEventListener fixed the problem for `click` but not for `mouseup` - I ended up getting around this issue by not using jQuery at all, instead I used `document.getElementById("mycanvas").dispatchEvent(savedEvent)`. I left this open in case I get a meaningful response to the bug report (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3660#issuecomment-299667529)

Comment: Why do you assign the click handler with plain JavaScript instead of jQuery, when you are using jQuery anyway..?

Comment: I wouldn't call that code by triggering the event handler that is a terrible practice. Refactor the code inside the event handler into it's own function then just call that function.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 - the code being used is a fairly old library, I'm in the process of refactoring it, but not finished yet. I use jQuery because I thought it would be easier

Comment: @ChipDean - it has to be triggered via the event handler, I'm recording a sequence of events, then replaying them.

Comment: When you do `$("#mycanvas")[0]` you are dereferencing the jQuery object and accessing the raw DOM object underneath.

Comment: @ChipDean - thanks, I'm not actually doing it, I just put it in the question as reference because I don't understand why there is a click handler assigned to it by default

Comment: This sounds like a jQuery bug. The documentation says you only need to use `stopPropagation()`. However, it also says **Although .trigger() simulates an event activation, complete with a synthesized event object, it does not perfectly replicate a naturally-occurring event.** Maybe this is part of the problem?

Comment: Does this happen if you use `.trigger('click')` instead of using a saved event object?

Comment: @Barmar, yes - `.trigger('click')` causes the same problem, also - I need the saved properties of the event to correctly emulate behaviour (e.g., cursor position). If it helps at all this is occurring in Meteor. The "bug" seems to be in this file: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/event/trigger.js on line 139